# Where are crafting stations the closest to a Trading Post representative?

Tags: guild-wars-2

When I'm crafting, I often discover that I just need a *little* bit more of some material, and the Trading Post is obviously the best place to acquire more in a hurry. While you can make purchases on the Trading Post from anywhere, you have to visit a rep to pick up your purchases. Where can I craft such that the distance from the crafting stations to a TP rep is the shortest possible?

Locations outside the major cities are fine, but I'd like a location where the crafting stations never get disabled (for example, [this event](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Find_the_escaped_experiments_and_bring_them_back_to_Zaxis#Notes) in Caledon Forest disables the nearby crafting stations).

Comment: I thought the ruined Lion's Arch had them sitting practically on top of each other.  Been many months since I've played properly though.

Comment: @Radhil It did have them right next to each other. Tragically Lion's Arch has been rebuilt and they're no longer very close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Royal Terrace](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Royal_Terrace) is has crafting stations closest to a trading post, followed closely by [Havoc's Heir](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Havoc%27s_Heir). Both of these require admission passes that can be purchased in the gem store (when available), though, with the permanent version of each costing 1000 gems.

The closest free trading post to crafting stations is in [Rata Sum](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Rata_Sum), by Accountancy Waypoint. With the crafting stations placed symmetrically around the trading post, bank, and guild bank, this area is especially convenient. The trading post in [The Grove](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/The_Grove) is also close to the crafting stations, but some more so than others.

The crafting stations in the citadel of your home [borderlands](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Borderlands) in WvW are also a convenient place for crafting, assuming there's no queue to get in, because going there and back doesn't cause you to lose your position in PvE or cost waypoint fees.

If you're only concerned with convenience for a short duration, it might be worth using a [Trading Post Express](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Trading_Post_Express), which are typically received from achievement rewards and daily rewards, but can also be obtained from the gem store.

Comment: Small correction: there are no waypoint fees associated with moving into, out of, or around WvW zones.

Comment: @Koviko: I believe that's why Brian (correctly) pointed out that it "_doesn't_ [...] cost waypoint fees" - going to WvW for crafting has always been one of the most convenient ways.

Comment: I don't know what I thought it said, now. I must have misread, somehow. My bad!

Comment: There's also Ebon Hawke - that is a short'ish run between TP/Bank and all the crafting spots

Comment: @DaveShaw I forgot to mention that, but it is a good one for the closest crafting stations there. Since they're all in a line, it's not very convenient for some of them, but it's great for others. I'll look into it if I remember next time I'm on.

Answer (score 0):

On **[Divinity's Reach](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Divinity's_Reach)** the **Ministers Waypoint** is very near to a trading post.

Just below that there's the **Commons Waypoint**, which is very near to some crafting stations (Armorsmithing, Jewelcrafting, Tailoring).

Using waypoints inside Divinity's Reach is free, so you can easily jump from here to there.

In case you need *other* crafts, since Divinity's Reach is so symmetrical, I think it's likely that there are other crafting stations near another waypoint, but I can't vouch for it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest free trading post to crafting stations is at **Hawkgates Waypoint** in Stronghold of Ebonhawke in Fields of Ruin.

Second closest is Rata Sum at the Accountancy Waypoint. Third is Divinity's Reach, where you can teleport to the TP and glide down to the crafting stations.